# iAd refresh slows down application drastically on cellular network

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I’m developing an **iOS game featuring iAds**. While I’m on my Wifi the game works perfectly fine. The moment I’m on a cellular network and the iAd reloads, all my animations have less then 10fps and the experience does suffer.

When I analyze this behaviour via the dev. tools, the game never uses more than 70MByte of Ram and 55% CPU (iPhone 6+).

From my current observations I would conclude, that the iAd view performs its activity with priority on the mainthread. Since the view does all its work by itself, I haven’t found a way to put it on a different thread manually. **Do you have any experience with this behaviour and how to solve it?**